# Why did the writer use a comma in this construction?

Tags: commas

Usually we don't use a comma before ***because***, except when the comma is a must to clear the meaning of the sentence. But l wonder why Randolph Quirk in his CGEL, page 616, uses a comma before ***because*** in this construction.

> He was drunk, ***because*** he had to support himself on a friend's arm.

Answer (score 1):

Without the comma, the sentence would imply that the man in question became drunk by supporting himself on somebody's arm (rather than by drinking alcohol).